# Azure functions: test locally in VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-typescript?pivots=nodejs-model-v3#run-the-function-locally
to run Azure function locally.

So, when I run:
[image]

I see error message on the bottom right corner of the VS Code:
[image]

And there is no way to see the detailed error message.

There is no way to debug...I want to know what caused this 500 error.

Any suggestions on how to run / test / debug Azure function locally in VS Code?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: @PravallikaKV  Thank you for your response. I have managed to check the local execution logs and the issue is described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76872587/nodejs-typescript-import-with-absolute-path-in-azure-function, Could you please take a look on this post?  I'll remove this question soon since it is not asked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can follow below steps to check the error logs in Visual studio code:**

1. Go to View=> Output=> it will open Output window with the logs.

[image]

2. Open command palette in visual studio code(ctrl+shift+p), search for `Developer:Show logs` (or) `Developer: Open Logs folder` and select.

[image]

- Once you select `Developer:Show logs` , it will display the logs in output window:

[image]

3. You can also run `func host start --debug` in VScode terminal, it will display the error details:

[image]

[image]