# Node.js Typescript Azure Function: Cannot import with absolute path ( minimal reproducible example attached)

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-functions

I have this Nodejs Typescript Azure function in local:

```
<root-directory>
├── README.md
├── dist
├── host.json
├── local.settings.json
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── sealworker
│   ├── constants
│   ├── errors
│   ├── function.json
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── interfaces
│   ├── sample.dat
│   ├── services
│   │     ├── worker.ts
│   │     └── ...
│   └── utils
│         ├── machineInfo.ts
│         └── ...
└── tsconfig.json
```

This is the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": "./sealworker",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "sealworker/*",
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*"
  ]
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "azure_function",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "prestart": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },

   ...
```

This is the `index.ts`, which imports a function from `./services/worker.ts`:

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { workerExec } from "./services/worker";

const sealWorkerFunction: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest
): Promise<void> {

...
```

and this is the `./services/worker.ts`:

```
import "dotenv/config";
import "reflect-metadata";
import { HttpRequest, Context } from "@azure/functions";
import { getMachineInfo } from "utils/machineInfo";

export const workerExec = async (req: HttpRequest, context: Context) => {
  context.log("start....");
```

And this is `utils/machineInfo.ts`:

```
import os from "os";

// Get the machine info that identifies the current host running this code;
export const getMachineInfo = () => {
  const machineInfo = {
    // The machine's hostname;
    hostname: os.hostname(),
    // the machine's number of CPUs;
    numCPUs: os.cpus().length,
  };
  return machineInfo;
};
```

Now it is complaining that the in line:

```
import { getMachineInfo } from "utils/machineInfo";
```

it cannot find module 'utils/machineInfo':

Error message:

```
[2023-08-10T03:59:00.616Z] Worker was unable to load entry point "dist/sealworker/index.js": Cannot find module 'utils/machineInfo'
[2023-08-10T03:59:00.616Z] Require stack:
[2023-08-10T03:59:00.616Z] - /Users/code/seal/azure_function/dist/sealworker/services/worker.js
[2023-08-10T03:59:00.616Z] - /Users/code/seal/azure_function/dist/sealworker/index.js
[2023-08-10T03:59:00.616Z] - /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5198/workers/node/dist/src/worker-bundle.js
[2023-08-10T03:59:00.616Z] - /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5198/workers/node/dist/src/nodejsWorker.js
```

I have tried different things with `"baseUrl"` and `"paths"` in `tsconfig.json`, and the values should be straight-forward and self explanatory now. But apparently I have made a mistake somewhere....

Any suggestions?

--------- UPDATE ---------

I have made a public minimal reproducible repo at: https://github.com/DaCao/minimal_reproducible_example

To reproduce, git clone this repo and open VS Code:

1. You need to have Azure tools plugin installed in VS Code;
2. In local WORKSPACE, click the azure functions icon and choose:

[image: Create Functon...]

3. Go through the creation process; select Programming Model V3;
4. After setting up the local project, build the nodejs:

```
john@MacBook-Pro:~/myapp/code/minimal_reproducible_example$ ls
host.json            local.settings.json  node_modules/        package-lock.json    package.json         sealworker/          tsconfig.json
john@MacBook-Pro:~/myapp/code/minimal_reproducible_example$ npm run-script build

> minimal_reproducible_example@1.0.0 build /Users/john/myapp/code/minimal_reproducible_example
> tsc

john@MacBook-Pro:~/myapp/code/minimal_reproducible_example$
```

you also need to have `Azure Function Core Tools` installed:

```
john@MacBook-Pro:~/myapp/code/minimal_reproducible_example$ func -v 
4.0.5198
```

and then just run:

```
john@MacBook-Pro:~/myapp/code/minimal_reproducible_example$ func start
```

you should see the error:

```
...

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-08-11T05:38:06.464Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2023-08-11T05:38:06.474Z] Worker was unable to load function sealworker: 'Cannot find module 'services/JobProcessor'
[2023-08-11T05:38:06.474Z] Require stack:
[2023-08-11T05:38:06.474Z] - /Users/john/myapp/code/minimal_reproducible_example/dist/sealworker/services/worker.js
[2023-08-11T05:38:06.474Z] - /Users/john/myapp/code/minimal_reproducible_example/dist/sealworker/index.js
[2023-08-11T05:38:06.474Z] - /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5198/workers/node/dist/src/worker-bundle.js
[2023-08-11T05:38:06.474Z] - /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5198/workers/node/dist/src/nodejsWorker.js'

...
```

Comment: can you add code machineInfo.ts please

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin  Yes, I just updated the post

Comment: Add **import { getMachineInfo } from "../utils/machineInfo";**, it will work

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin  Thanks. I can get it running by importing with relative path for now.  But in the long term, I would like to figure out a way to import with absolute path. It is nicer that way.

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin  I have generated a minimal reproducible example in the updated post. If you can take a look, i'll be really grateful. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, `… from 'utils/…'` isn't absolute path, it is an alias for a relative path

Answer (score 3):

Based on your stack trace, I guess you compile your code with `tsc` and then gets executed with `node`. Keep in mind that if you build with `tsc`, the absolute paths will end up not converting to relative path at all.

As result of that, I would recommend to have an extra step to convert those paths by using [`tsc-alias`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias)

```js
// package.json
{
  "build": "tsc && tsc-alias",
}
```

**Update after looking at the example repo:**

I noted that you set `rootDir: "."` which is to include your built code under the same dir `sealworker` but unfortunately this setup prevents `tsc-alias` from working properly for some reason that I have no idea too (it could be a bug to report to them).

Anyway I would suggest either set up another command to move the built code into the dir or even remove this setup and place built code under `dist` is enough.

Comment: exactly, now I have `"build": "tsc",`;  Thank you I will try that

Comment: nope it does not work...

Comment: do you mind sharing a minimum reproducible repo? probably with just a simple index file with the absolute import

Comment: Sure, I have generated a minimal reproducible example in the updated post.  @tmhao2005

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C I looked at your code and update the answer with my find

Comment: hey @Kid_Learning_C have you checked my update yet?

Comment: Thank you @tmhao2005,  i have given up on using the absolute path. I just settled with using relative paths like `import {} from ../../utils/filesname`